# How to automatically generate C header file using CMake?

Tags: c, header, cmake

I'm looking for a way to automatically generate a header file. This file is the public interface of a library and i want to "fill" some structures and stuff before compilation.

For example, in the private header I have a structure with useful fields :

```
typedef struct mystuff_attr_t {
  int                      _detachstate;
  mystuff_scope_t          _scope;
  cpu_set_t                _cpuset;
  size_t                   _stacksize;
  void*                    _stackaddr;
} mystuff_attr_t;
```

And I would like to have this structure in the public header without the fields but with the same size (currently done manually) this way :

```
typedef struct mystuff_attr_t {
  char _opaque[ 20 ]; 
} mystuff_attr_t;
```

I would like to have this automatically generated by CMake when creating the build system in order to avoid bad size struct in public interface when I change the struct in private header.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In fact, CMake allow you to generate files (using `configure_file (file.h.in file.h)` ) and also to check a type size (using `check_type_size ("type" header.h)`) so it's easy to combine those two to have a proper public header. Here is the piece of code I use in CMakeList.txt :

```
# Where to search for types :
set (CMAKE_EXTRA_INCLUDE_FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/private_type.h)

# Type1 :
check_type_size ("type1_t" MY_SIZEOF_TYPE1_T)

# Generate public header :
configure_file (${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/pub_type.h.in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/pub_type.h)

# Need to set this back to nothing :
set (CMAKE_EXTRA_INCLUDE_FILES)
```

And in the public header pub_type.h.in :

```
#define MY_SIZEOF_TYPE1_T ${MY_SIZEOF_TYPE1_T}
```

This works pretty good :)

Comment: You should specify that you need to add the line: include(CheckTypeSize).

Answer (score 4):

The [Makeheaders](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/mkhdr/) tool ([manual](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/mkhdr/makeheaders.html)).

Answer (score 2):

I would write an exe that creates the header.

for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PUBLIC(TYPE) \
printf( "typedef struct %s { char _opaque[ %d ]; } %s;\n", #TYPE, sizeof(TYPE), #TYPE )

int main()
  {
  // start header stuff

  PUBLIC(mystuff_attr_t);

  // end header stuff
  }
```

Comment: I already thought of that but I was wondering if a tool like cmake had some usefull module to help me doing this. By the way, I would rather write a shell script instead of an exe as long as it's for unix platforms.

Comment: Thanks. The advantage of using a bin is that you can get the compiler to work out the sizes for you. Using a script you will need to do it yourself and you might get it wrong.